# Click is NOT working when element is not visible in a screen Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor-net

I have few `links` in a page. There are few `links` which will be visible if you scroll down the page..

I am using `C# - Protractor for script automation`.

It says that element is displayed, when i check boolean condition. But if i `click` the `link` it does not navigate to the actual page.

When use `debug`, while executing the `click` command if i scroll down the page then it works fine. How to resolve this scroll down issue?

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = ngDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript('arguments[0].click()', targetElement); 
Getting error that Too many characters in character literal
```

Is this syntax correct?

Thanks

Comment: selenium automatically scrolls to the element before performing a click on it, so something else must be going on here.

Comment: It clicks but stays on the same screen..

Comment: Why aren't you using c#? Is there some particular reason you want to execute it through JS? Selenium has a IWebElement.Click() function. You just fetch your element by using the IWebDriver.FindElement() function, it will return the element as IWebElement. Then you just run the Click() method on that element. Maybe JS is the reason something's being wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
 var elem = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("something"));
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem);
```